# Как лучше всего получать данные с сайта?

Tags: javascript

Как лучше всего посоветуете работать с этим API [http://qps.ru/api?url=ссылка](http://qps.ru/api?url=%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) на любой сайт

И есть ли способ на js Без использования jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var urlIn = 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513735/';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://qps.ru/api?url=' + urlIn, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    document.body.textContent = urlIn + ' >> ' + xhr.responseText;
  }
}
xhr.send(null);
```